Connecting to database I host with QGIS Cloud
I'm interested to learn whether it is possible to use my own PostGIS database that I host with QGIS Cloud rather than keep paying for more storage from QGIS Cloud?

No, it is not possible to publish data from databases other than the QGIS Cloud databases in order to bypass the storage limit.
